# Are the supports of $Ext^i(M,N)$ eventually periodic? 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $R$ be a Noetherian, commutative ring and $M,N$ be finitely generated $R$-modules.

**Question**: Do the sets of minimal primes of $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ (for a fixed pair of $M,N$) become periodic for $i\gg 0$?

**Background/Motivation**: In this part I will assume $R$ local (I don't think it's significant for the question, but some statements will be awkward in general). I was motivated to ask after this [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32137/the-associated-prime-ideals-of-exti-rm-n).

It is known that the asymptotic behavior of these $\text{Ext}$ is governed by the singularity of $R$. For instance, if $R$ is regular, then $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,N)=0$ for $i>\dim R$ because $R$ has finite global dimension equals to $\dim R$.

If $R$ is a hypersurface, then it follows from Eisenbud's [original paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1999875) on matrix factorization that the minimal resolution of  $M$ becomes eventually periodic of period $2$ after $\dim R$ spots, so the answer in this case is also affirmative.

With a little bit more work, one can show that the supports of $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ (in fact, the annihilators) become eventually periodic of period $2$ when $R$ is a local *complete intersection*.

EDIT: As Karl's comment indicated, perhaps a more realistic question is:

**Question 2**: Is the union of all minimal primes of $\text{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ for $i>0$ a finite set?

One situation when the answer is trivially yes is when $\text{Spec}R$ has an isolated singularity.

I think the answer is no (even for question 2) in general, but not sure how to construct an example.

Comment: Long, can you say something about the "little bit more work" needed to show the c.i. case?  Also, is the answer known if $R$ is c.i. (or hypersurface) on the punctured spectrum?

Comment: @Graham: It follows from a simple observation, see for example Cor 2.4 in http://www.math.ku.edu/~hdao/asymptotic.pdf and the fact that the total Ext module is Noetherian over the ring of (co)homology operators, defined in Eisenbud's paper. 

Comment: Long, is it clear that the union of the set of supports of these Ext modules is a finite set?

Comment: @Karl: no, not to me. 

Comment: Is minimal of $\cup \mathrm{Ass} \mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M, N)$ finite?

Comment: This paper contains some relevant results which might be of interest https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004115000778 ... apparently the question whether $\cup_{i\ge 0} Ass (Ext^i_R(M,R))$ is finite for a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ over a Noetherian local ring $R$, was first asked by Vasconcelos

Comment: So this still remains an open question? Even finiteness of the support?